# How to generate an gnuplot with coordenates and without creating a file?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to create a graph with some coordenates and then line them up.
for example:
1; 3 /
2; 4 /
4; 5
but without creating a file with that information. Can i plot the coordenates?

```
# To view in X:
# To print on a PostScript printer:
set terminal png
set output "graph.png"


set title "Teste Plot"
set xlabel "t"
set ylabel "nt batatas"

set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:10]

1, 3
2, 4
4, 5

# Plot
plot "-" with linespoints
```

Comment: In gnuplot console, e.g. check `help inline`.

Answer (score 0):

Check `help inline` or `help special-filenames`...
well, documentation does not seem to contain an example for `plot "-"`... maybe somewhere hidden...

Try the following:

**Code:**

```
reset session
set title "Teste Plot"
set xlabel "t"
set ylabel "nt batatas"

set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:10]
set datafile separator comma

# Plot
plot "-" with linespoints title "my inline data"
1, 3
2, 4
4, 5
e
```

or (I would prefer this way):

```
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1, 3
2, 4
4, 5
EOD

set title "Teste Plot"
set xlabel "t"
set ylabel "nt batatas"

set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:10]
set datafile separator comma

# Plot
plot $Data u 1:2 with linespoints title "my inline data"
```

**Result:**

[image]